# Open ports with iptables — still closed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to open some ports for a [gameserver](http://pzwiki.net/wiki/Multiplayer_FAQ), which is running on my Linux vServer (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit). The game needs the following ports:

```
16261 (UDP)
16262 (TCP) // Player 1
16263 (TCP) // Player 2
16264 (TCP) // Player 3
16265 (TCP) // Player 4
// ...
```

Since I'm not really experienced with Linux, I searched for some ways to open ports on Ubuntu. I followed the [steps described here](http://www.putorius.net/2011/05/basic-of-iptables-opening-ports-on.html) and entered:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 16261 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 16262 -j ACCEPT
```

To make sure that it worked I checked iptables with `iptables -L` and got a list like that:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8880
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:poppassd
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmptype 8 code 0
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:16261
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:16262
```

The two new entries are in fact in the list, but when I [checked](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to see if the two ports are open it said that both ports (16261/26262) are still closed. What am I doing wrong? A Teamspeak 3 and CS:GO server are already running without problems...

**EDIT:** I read somewhere else that I can also check the open ports with `netstat -ntulp`. If I enter this command the two ports don't show up in the list.

Comment: The ports are open in the server. What about the router? You tested from outside your network, so your router needs to have those ports routed to your server.

Comment: @jcbermu I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this is not a private home server. It is hosted somewhere... I don't think they are open in the server - if I check with `netstat -ntulp` the two ports don't show up.

Comment: OK. If `netstat -ntulp` don't show them, they are closed.

Comment: If it's hosted on someone else's hardware, maybe you need to ask the someone else about opening some ports